# With ActiveRecord, how do I write a where statement that only includes objects whose values aren't blank/nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

The title isn't too explanatory, but basically I have a Game model, and each game has_many Stats. These stats also belong_to an Athlete, who has_many Games. Each Stat has a Stat_Type, and I'm collecting the StatTypes that I need in the following code:

```
@games = Athlete.first.games
unless @games.blank?
    @sport_position_stat_types = @games.first.stats.not_calculated.order("id ASC").collect(&:stat_type)
end
```

This works fine, but I need a way to remove any stat_type in this list where there are NO stats of that stat_type in ANY of the games that have a value.

Basically, I have all the stat_types I need right now, but I need to limit @sport_position_stat_types to only stat_types that have stats with values in that athlete's games collection.

So here's what I need:

```
Athlete
-->Games
  -->Stats
    -->Stat_Types (I need all of these as long as there is at least ONE stat of that stat_type that is in the above Athlete's Games, and doesn't have a nil Value column--aka it has a value)
```

I hope this explains it well enough. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT::

This is what is returned (@sport_position_stat_types):

```
[#<StatType id: 270, sport_id: 6, name: "Return Touchdowns", unit: "", created_at: 
"2012-12-31 19:20:37", updated_at: "2013-04-29 15:19:59", lower_is_better: false, 
sport_position_id: 5, display_as_decimal: false, game: true, placement: 28, 
stat_type_category_id: 1, abbreviation: nil, calculated: false>, 
#<StatType id: 269, sport_id: 6, name: "Receiving Touchdowns", unit: "", created_at: "2012-
12-31 19:20:10", updated_at: "2013-04-29 15:19:59", lower_is_better: false, 
sport_position_id: 5, display_as_decimal: false, game: true, placement: 29, 
stat_type_category_id: 1, abbreviation: nil, calculated: false>, #<StatType id: 268, 
sport_id: 6, name: "Yards Per Catch", unit: "", created_at: "2012-12-31 19:18:33", 
updated_at: "2013-04-29 15:19:59", lower_is_better: false, sport_position_id: 5, 
display_as_decimal: true, game: true, placement: 30, stat_type_category_id: 1, abbreviation: nil, calculated: false>,
 #<StatType id: 267, sport_id: 6, name: "Receiving Yards", unit: "", created_at: "2012-12-31
 19:18:00", updated_at: "2013-04-29 15:19:59", lower_is_better: false, sport_position_id: 5,
 display_as_decimal: false, game: true, placement: 31, stat_type_category_id: 1, 
abbreviation: nil, calculated: false>, #<StatType id: 266, sport_id: 6, name: "Catches", 
unit: "", created_at: "2012-12-31 19:16:24", updated_at: "2013-04-29 15:19:59", 
lower_is_better: false, sport_position_id: 5, display_as_decimal: false, game: true, 
placement: 32, stat_type_category_id: 1, abbreviation: nil, calculated: false>, 
#<StatType id: 265, sport_id: 6, name: "Fumbles", unit: "", created_at: "2012-12-31 
19:09:41", updated_at: "2013-04-29 15:19:59", lower_is_better: true, sport_position_id: 5, 
display_as_decimal: false, game: true, placement: 33, stat_type_category_id: 1, 
abbreviation: nil, calculated: false>, 
#<StatType id: 264, sport_id: 6, name: "Rushing Touchdowns", unit: "", created_at: "2012-12-
31 19:09:10", updated_at: "2013-08-20 15:48:48", lower_is_better: false, sport_position_id:
 5, display_as_decimal: false, game: true, placement: 34, stat_type_category_id: 4, 
abbreviation: nil, calculated: false>, 
#<StatType id: 263, sport_id: 6, name: "Rush Long", unit: "", created_at: "2012-12-31
 19:08:42", updated_at: "2013-08-20 15:48:48", lower_is_better: false, sport_position_id: 5,
 display_as_decimal: false, game: true, placement: 35, stat_type_category_id: 4, 
abbreviation: nil, calculated: false>, 
#<StatType id: 262, sport_id: 6, name: "Rush Yards per Carry", unit: "yard", created_at: 
"2012-12-31 19:06:49", updated_at: "2013-08-20 15:48:48", lower_is_better: false, 
sport_position_id: 5, display_as_decimal: true, game: true, placement: 36, 
stat_type_category_id: 4, abbreviation: nil, calculated: false>, 
#<StatType id: 261, sport_id: 6, name: "Rush Yards", unit: "yard", created_at: "2012-12-31
 19:06:01", updated_at: "2013-08-20 15:48:47", lower_is_better: false, sport_position_id: 5,
 display_as_decimal: false, game: true, placement: 37, stat_type_category_id: 4, 
abbreviation: nil, calculated: false>, 
#<StatType id: 260, sport_id: 6, name: "Rushes", unit: "", created_at: "2012-12-31
 19:05:24", updated_at: "2013-08-20 15:48:48", lower_is_better: false, sport_position_id: 5,
 display_as_decimal: false, game: true, placement: 38, stat_type_category_id: 4, 
abbreviation: nil, calculated: false>]
```

Comment: what's being returned with this query?

Comment: An array of StatTypes

Comment: could you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@games = Athlete.first.games
unless @games.blank?
    @sport_position_stat_types = @games.first.stats.not_calculated.order("id ASC").collect(&:stat_type)
    @sport_position_stat_types.reject(&:blank?)
end
```

Comment: This won't work because the stat_type itself won't be blank, I just have to see if that stats in each game of @games that have that stat_type have a blank value